# How to specify the empty string?

Tags: latex

For a script, I need to set a command/variable (not sure about the right term here) to the empty string by default. I assumed that `\def\theemptystring{}` would suffice, but then `\theemptystring` is not considered empty.

```
% Generate description list of numbered lists of procedural mechanics by category from CSV
    % Parameters: [label] file
\newcommand{\csvpmech}[2][]{%
    \begin{description}\ifstrempty{#1}{}{\label{#1}}%
        \def \prevcat {}%
        \csvreader{#2}{}{%
            \ifstrempty{\prevcat}{%
                % first item
                \item[\csvcoli]\begin{enumerate}\item\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}\or\equal{\csvcolii}{}}{}{\label{#1_\csvcolii}}\pmech[\csvcoliii][\csvcoliv]{\csvcolv}{\csvcolvi}%
                \def \prevcat \csvcoli%
            }{%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\csvcoli}{}\or\equal{\csvcoli}{\prevcat}}{%
                    % same category
                    \item\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}\or\equal{\csvcolii}{}}{}{\label{#1_\csvcolii}}\pmech[\csvcoliii][\csvcoliv]{\csvcolv}{\csvcolvi}%
                }{%
                    % new category
                    \end{enumerate}\item[\csvcoli]\begin{enumerate}\item\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}\or\equal{\csvcolii}{}}{}{\label{#1_\csvcolii}}\pmech[\csvcoliii][\csvcoliv]{\csvcolv}{\csvcolvi}%
                    \def \prevcat \csvcoli%
                }
            }%
        }%
        \ifstrempty{\prevcat}{}{\end{enumerate}}%
    \end{description}%
}
```

The idea is to grab a CSV file and display it contents organized by category. `pmech` formats a single item. Input might look like this:

```
Category,Identifier,Context,Input,Parameter,Effect
Meat Boy movement,Move,,Left stick horizontal,Analog position,Meat Boy moves left/right at a speed increasing with absolute difference between position and default
,Sprint,,RT + left stick left/right,Analog position,Meat Boy moves faster
Meat Boy jumping,Jump,Meat Boy on ground,A,Duration,Apply upwards velocity increasing with duration
,Wall jump,Meat boy on wall,A,Duration,Apply upwards and sideways velocity opposite side of wall increasing with duration
```

Comment: It is and it isn't. To help you fully, we need more information though. What does this "script" look like? Is it entirely in LaTeX? What tests do you perform to check for this empty macro?

Comment: Thanks! Does the script I added to the question make sense to you?